# Variance of a random variable conditional on a function of two random variables

Tags: probability

The random variables $U,V$ are distributed $U,V \sim N(0,1)$ but independently and $Y = x(V) + U$ where $x(V)$ is some linear function of the form $x(V) = aV$. If $p$ is also some linear function of the from $p(Y) = cY$ where $c$ is just a slope coefficient, what is the variance of $V$ conditional on $p(Y)$ i.e $$Var\left(V\mid p(Y)\right)$$ 
I am approaching the problem from a computational point of view but closed form intuition would be appreciated.

Comment: $X(v)=ax$. Should it be $av$ instead of $ax$? And $P(y)$ is simply $cy$ or not?

Comment: If the question is to compute var$(v\mid cw)$ with $w=au+v$ and $c\ne0$, note that $v=(w-az)/(1+a^2)$ where $z=u-av$ and that $(w,z)$ is normal independent with var$(z)=1+a^2$, hence var$(v\mid w)=$var$(az/(1+a^2))=a^2/(1+a^2)$. Note finally that var$(v\mid w)=$var$(v\mid cw)$ for every $c\ne0$.

Comment: Just edited. Apologies for the mistake.

Comment: Hence indeed the question is as guessed in my comment above hence said comment answers said question.